# How to check for the active Application?

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a VBA-Macro, activated via a Ribbon-Button for exporting selected Mails into a certain folder.

I'd like to make this Macro available in Word and Excel (for exporting doc/xls) into the same folder-structure.

Is it possible to check for the active application and then decide if a Mail(s)-Export or a simple Doc/Xls-Export should be done?

Comment: Hm... u mean [**Application.Name**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841101(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: thats all? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with multiple Applications probably the easiest way to identify one would be to use [`Application.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841101(v=office.15).aspx) property.

If you happen to have passed an object of some type that has the `.Application` property you can also call that. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272782/why-does-every-class-in-vba-have-an-application-property) for details.

Also, with most MS-Office objects you can go up the hierarchy using the `.Parent` property to get all the way up to the Application, ie. `.someObj.Parent.Parent.Parent.Application.Name`